# How to make default TreeView (System.Windows.Controls) have the same style as RadTreeView (telerik)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I tried simply changing the <*TreeView*> to <*RadTreeView*> but it messes up some code behind methods, so i thought i could just apply the style, but nothing i tried works.

The code below works fine, i tried change the static resource to RadTreeViewItemStyle it compiles with no problems, but then i get an error on runtime that says "**Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type 'TreeViewItem**' "

```
<TreeView.Resources>
  <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTreeViewItem}" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>;
```

Comment: Are you using Telerik?

Comment: What's the `TargetType` of `MetroTreeViewItem`? You can only apply it to elements of this type. A `RadTreeView` is not a `TreeView`.

Comment: The `TargetType` of `MetroTreeViewItem` is `TreeViewItem`, and i guess `RadTreeViewItem`'s `TargetType` isn't, but my question is how to get around that and apply the `RadTreeView` style to the default `TreeView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***First solution:*** you could make your `TreeView` extend the `RadTreeView`. I think `RadTreeView` has some special dependency properties and also seems to use it's own custom item container. That's why the Telerik style(s) didn't work properly on the `TreeView`, although it compiles in the first place.

***Second solution:*** could be to extract the `RadTreeView` style and refactor it, so that it can apply to the WPF `TreeView`.

In Visual Studio, you have two options.
First option is to follow this 5 simple steps:

1. Go to the XAML Designer and open the *Design Pane* (Shift+F7)
2. Select the element you wish to extract the style from (`RadTreeView`) and right click on it
3. In the context menu select *Edit Template -> Edit a Copy*
4. In the dialog enter a name for the new extracted style and click *Ok*
5. You are now back in the XAML Designer. Look for the new style. It was added to the same file where you selected the element tag to extract the style and is named like you have specified before. It's usually added to the top level resource dictionary

To extract the items template repeat steps 1 and 2. Then select *Edit Additional Template -> Edit Generated Items (ItemTemplate)* from the context menu. Continue with step 4 and 5.

Second option is to follow this 7 simple steps to extract an element's style:

1. Go to the XAML Designer and select the tag of the element you wish to extract the style from (`RadTreeView`)
2. Then go to the *Properties* pane and scroll down to the *Miscellaneous* section
3. Expand the *Miscellaneous* section and scroll down to the *Style* field
4. On the right of this field is a small square. Left click this square to open a context menu
5. In the context menu select *Convert to New Resource...*. This opens a dialog.
6. In the dialog give the new style a name and click *Ok*
7. You are now back in the XAML Designer. Look for the new style. It was added to the same file where you selected the element tag to extract the style and is named like you have specified before. It's usually added to the top level resource dictionary

To extract the template repeat steps 1 and 2. Then go to the *Template* field. Continue with steps 4 to 7.

***Third solution:*** refactor your code-behind in order to make it work with a `RadTreeView`.

***Fourth solution:*** if it's only the item container that makes the style(s) incompatible, tune your `TreeView` to use the Telerik item conatiner version (instead of the `TreeViewItem`). You can do this by extending `TreeView` and then overriding the default items container:

```
public class MyExtendedTreeView : TreeView
{    
  protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
  {
    return (item is RadTreeViewItem);
  }

  protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
  {
    return new RadTreeViewItem();
  }
}
```

I think this are your options.

Comment: First solution that came to my mind was the second solution you proposed (i think it need less work too), do you know any ways to extract the `RadTreeView` style?

Comment: @KyriakosXatzisavvas Updated the answer to show how to extract the style and template.

Comment: It still doesn't work immediately , but i guess with some tweaks it will work. I think this is as close as it gets to a proper answer, thanks!

Comment: @KyriakosXatzisavvas Better use the first approach and extract the style via the XAML Designer pane. The style is more detailed I think